# Regular Expression - Need Help Matching Everything Except For A Certain String

Tags: regex, string, expression, numeric

After countless hours of trying to get this regex to work (including looking all over StackOverflow), I thought I'd reach out for help on here as I have not been successful).

I have tried creating a regex to match everything and to not match any parameters that look like this:

- `text=3242ffs3F34`

The data after the `=` sign can be random (its a mixture of numeric and string characters) and is never the same. So far I have created the following regex below, which is almost doing what I am after but it does not work.

```
\b(?!text=.*)\b\S+
```

Assistance is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I will be using the regex to match everything in a file but to filter out all parameters that look like this:

- `text=3242ffs3F34`

Below is an example of how the config file will look like:

```
This is a test
test=asda
test2=22rr2
text=3242ffs3F34
test5=hello
```

Comment: I saw this almost exact question here about 12 hours ago, under a different username/account.  At that time, you received several comments that your question was not clear.  Please edit your question and show us several samples of input, along with what you want to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match everything except strings containing `LAST_DOMINO_TIME=` as substring you can use the expression:

```
(?!.*\bLAST_DOMINO_TIME=.*$)^.*$
```

- `(?!` Negative lookahead.

  - `.*` Match anything.
  - `\b` Word boundary.
  - `LAST_DOMINO_TIME=` Literal substring.
  - `.*$` Anything up to end of string.
- `)` Close lookahead.
- `^.*$` Assert position beginning of line, match anything up to end of line.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/f0PLPZ/2).

Comment: Thank you very much, you legend! :)

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help.